# If $f(x) + f'(x) \le 0$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$, then for what preimage we have $f(x) < 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $f(x) \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ be a real-valued function such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$. If, in addition, we have $f(x) + f'(x) \le 0$ (equality holds if and only if $x = 0$), can we conclude that

1. $\exists x$ such that $f(x) < 0$ ?
2. for $x \in B_{\epsilon}(0)$ there holds $f(x) < 0$ ? ($B_\epsilon$ denotes some neighborhood within $\epsilon$)
3. for $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ there holds $f(x) < 0$ ?

If not, which extra conditions are required for each proposition to be true?

(The extra conditions may be, for example, $f \in C^\infty$, or $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=e^xf(x)$. Then the conditions read $g(0)=0$, $g'(0)=0$ and $g'(x)< 0$ for $x\ne0$. The condition $f(x)<0$ is then equivalent to $g(x)<0$.

As one can see, $g$ has to be falling, and in fact strongly so, by the mean value theorem. Thus $g(x)<0$ for all $x>0$. By the same argument, $g(x)>0$ for $x<0$, and the same holds for $f$.

Comment: $f \in C^1$ is enough for this conclusion?

Comment: Yes, as then also $g\in C^1$ and $\frac{g(x_2)-g(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}<0$ for all $x_1<x_2\le0$ and $0\le x_1<x_2$ by mean value theorem, proving the strictly falling property.

Comment: Is $f \in C^1$ enough for this conclusion? I thought about some stronger condition like $f$ must be uniformly or Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: One more question, if we have $f'(x)+f(x)<0$ for $x > 0$, by mean value theorem $f(x)=xf'(a)$ for some $a \in (0,x)$, then we get $f'(x)+xf'(a) < 0$ for all $0<a<x$, can we directly obtain that $f'(x)<0$ for all $x > 0$, then by mean value theorem $f(x) = xf'(a) < 0$ ?

Comment: @AnalysisNewbie : No, that does not appear helpful as there is no control over what $a$ is or how large $f'(a)$ is relative to $f'(x)$.